# removing ambiguity from the miniJava grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, antlr, ambiguity, ambiguous

It seems that our grammar have some ambiguities.But we really don't know how we can remove them. we really need someone to teach us step by step. for example in our grammar how can we remove ambiguity on "this" ,"public","private" ...

```
    Program: ( ClassDeclaration )*  'eot';
ClassDeclaration:  'class'   ID '{' ( FieldDeclaration | MethodDeclaration )* '}' ;
FieldDeclaration: Declarators   ID';' ;
MethodDeclaration: Declarators   ID'(' ParameterList? ')' 
'{' Statement* ( 'returnExpression' ';' )? '}' ;
    Declarators : ( 'public'|  'private')?  'static'? Type ;
Type : PrimType | ClassType | ArrType; 
PrimType :  INT|  'boolean'|  'void';
ClassType : ID;
ArrType : ( INT| ClassType ) '[' ']' ;
ParameterList : Type   ID( ',' Type   ID)* ;
ArgumentList : Expression ( ',' Expression )* ;
Reference : ( 'this'|   ID) ( '.'   ID)* ;
Statement : 
'{' Statement* '}'
| Type   ID'=' Expression ';' 
| Reference ( '[' Expression ']' )? '=' Expression ';'
| Reference '(' ArgumentList? ')' ';' 
|  'if''(' Expression ')' Statement ( 'elseStatement' )? 
|  'while''(' Expression ')' Statement ;

Expression : 
Reference ( '['Expression ']')? 
| Reference '('ArgumentList? ')'
|  'unopExpression' 
|   'binopExpression' 
| '('Expression ')'
|  ( ID|FLOAT)|  'true'|  'false'
|  'new'(  ID'('')'|  INT'['Expression ']'|   ID'['Expression ']') ;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
    WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

STRING
    :  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'\'') )* '\''
    ;

CHAR:  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\''|'\\') ) '\''
    ;

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

Comment: Can you explain the ambiguity in your grammar ?